# vb.net listview includes table deleted

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem. I'm using VB.net 2015 and Access 2016. I show in a ListView some table names of an Access db. If a delete any table and close the form, when I open this form again and complete the ListView this deleted table appears again in the list.

Which could be the problem?

Comment: How do you get the table names into the ListView? (providing some code would make this question more attractive to the community)

Comment: As @Verdolino requested, please provide code of how you are getting the table names into the ListView. If you are reading the Access DB at run time and checking it for tables names, then I would venture to guess there is some odd behavior where old table names are not deleted from the information_schema (or whatever the Access equivalent is of information_schema).

Comment: And adding to what @SpencerDoak said, if you are using Entity Framework or LINQ to ODBC, the model will not automatically update if a table is removed from the database. There are mechanisms to manually update the model... but we would need more info.